# Is acceptable Entity circular reference in domain model?

Tags: java, oop

I've seen a lot of domains designed with circular reference. The image below describes a simple example for understand the question: A company has employees and departments and a department has employees, who belong to a department.

Logically, the model allows a employee who works for a company be related with a department of another company - of course, hypothetically, if business logic validation fails.

In some more complex cases, and according to the business rules, I don´t see another way to model.

Is it acceptable?

Thanks in advance.

[image: Simple Cirular Reference Example]

Comment: When you mean related, are you talking about inheritance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is absolutely fine to have such kind of circular association.

Of course there are lots of pitfall that shoot your feet.  However with extra cautious such kind of relationship is fact not always harmful.

Things that you need to pay extra attention includes:

- Try to define the "owner" of the relationship.  This is especially important if you are going to persist the entity
- Make sure the owning relationships are not circular.  For example, in your example, you can define `Company` owning the `Company-Department` and `Company-Employee` relationship, and `Department` owning the `Department-Employee` relationship
- Make sure the relationship is consistent.  For example, for the bi-directional relationship between `Employee` and `Department`, when you remove an `Employee` from a `Department`, make sure you remove the `Department` from `Employee` consistently.
- Try to minimize the way to manage relationship.  For example, instead of providing both `Department#addEmployee(Employee)` and `Employee#addDepartment(Department)`, just provide `Department#addEmployee(Employee)`.  This should make your work of keeping consistency easier.

Still, if you can manage to make it uni-directional and non-circular, it is always easier to handle.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to avoid the situation you've described (where an employee "E" is associated with a department "D", but "D" and "E" are associated with different companies), you can try making your object model a tree, with no cycles:

```
Company --> Department --> Employee
```

There are trade-offs here. For example, this model doesn't directy handle Employees with no Department (although this could be papered over with a fake department like NoDepartment). This model may also require two "hops" to get from Employee to Company.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Always is it possible, I try to make relationships non-circular, as you suggest. However, sometimes, the business rule itself doesn't allow it.